# convert IEnumerable<double> to double

Tags: c#, linq, double, ienumerable

I need  return sum of elements with odd indexes in the array of doubles
This is my code:

```
 public static double EvaluateSumOfElementsOddPositions(double[] inputData)
    {
        
        var sum = inputData
            .Select((v, i) => new { Group = (i % 2 != 0), Value = v })
            .GroupBy(x => x.Group)
            .Select(g => g.Sum(y => y.Value));
        return sum ;
    }
```

But I have a mistake:
Can't implicitly convert IEnumerable to double.
I don't know how I can deal with that... Help, please!

Comment: `.Select(g => g.Sum(y => y.Value)).Sum()`

Comment: You could simply use where override like this :`.Where((i,x)=> x % 2== 1).Sum();`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is something like:

```
public static double EvaluateSumOfElementsOddPositions(double[] inputData)
{
    return inputData
        .Where((data, index) => index % 2 != 0)
        .Sum();
}
```

You don't need to group the elements if you are not going to use elements at even indices.

Comment: @TeSla Glad I was able to help. Could you please upvote the answer and mark it as a solution?

Comment: I've tried, but I have: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Comment: Ok, no problem :) Good luck with coding!

Answer (score 0):

Although it is a nice exercise to try to do this using LINQ, it is not very efficient.

GroupBy will create a `Dictionary<Tkey, ICollection<TResult>>`, or to be more precise: a Lookup Table. For every element, it will extract the key and the TResult. For ever element it will check if the Key is in the Lookup Table.

- If not, it will put the TResult in a new `ICollection<TResult>` and add the Key and the collection to the table.
- It the Key is in the table it will add the TResult to the end of the collection.

This is quite a lot of work, while in fact the only thing you want is:

```
public static IEnumerable<double> ToEveryOtherDouble(this IEnumerable<double> doubles)
{
    bool everyOther = false;
    // will return elements with index 1, 3, 5, ...
    // start with true if you want 0, 2, 4, ...
   
    foreach (double d in doubles)
    {
        if (everyOther)
            yield return d;
        everyOther = !everyOther;
    }
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<double> inputData = ....
double sum = inputData.ToEveryOtherDouble().Sum();
```

If you insist on using LINQ, make two groups: a group containing doubles with the even indexes, and a group containing doubles with the odd indexes.

So Key of the group: `i % 2`

```
double sum = inputData.Select( (d, index) => new
{
    Index = index,
    Value  = d,
})
.GroupBy(x => x.Index % 2,   // keySelector: groups with key 0 and key 1

    // parameter elementSelector: specify the elements of each group
    x => x.Value)            // as elements of the group, we only need the double
```

Result of the GroupBy: two groups. A group with key 0 and a group with key 1. The group with key 0 has as elements the doubles at even indexes, the group with key 1 has as elements the doubles at odd indexes.

Continuing the LINQ: if you want only the even indexes:

```
.Where(group => group.Key == 0).Sum();
```

### Conclusion

The choice is yours: which one is easier to read, reuse, maintain and unit test:

```
double sum = inputData.Select( (d, index) => new
{
    Index = index,
    Value  = d,
})
.GroupBy(x => x.Index % 2, x => x.Value)
.Where(group => group.Key == 0)
.Sum();
```

Or:

```
double sum = inputData.ToEveryOtherDouble().Sum();
```

Comment: Why not just use the `Where` override without grouping?